# Send is not defined (suggest command)

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, send, defined

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined` What did i do wrong? I dont see where i should define it. Probably just a dumb thing i forgot. I would appreciate all improvements/suggestions.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'suggest',
    aliases: ['sug', 'suggestion'],
    description: 'Suggest something for the Bot',
    execute( client, message, args) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        message.channel.send(Suggest something for the Bot or send "cancel" to cancel the suggestion)
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1,})
            .then(async(collected) => {
                if (collected.first().content.toLowerCase() == 'cancel') {
                message.reply("The suggestion has been cancelled.")
                } 
                else { client.channels.get("702825446248808519").send(collected.first().content)
                    message.channel.send(Your suggestion has been sent)
                }
            })
    },
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
};
```

Comment: Clearly, message.channel is undefined. Where is message set?

Comment: message is in the execute()

Comment: `message` is the second parameter to execute(), but it's obviously set by the caller. What it the caller setting it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message.channel.send(Suggest something for the Bot or send "cancel" to cancel the suggestion)
```

This won't work , with this code you are trying to send a var that doesn't exist, i guess you are trying to send a text so it should look like this :

```
message.channel.send('Suggest something for the Bot or send "cancel" to cancel the suggestion')
```

It's the same here :

```
message.channel.send(Your suggestion has been sent)
```

Becomes :

```
message.channel.send('Your suggestion has been sent')
```

Also if you are using discord.js v12 change `client.channels.get` to `client.channels.cache.get`

I hope this helps

Comment: Ah idk i think i manged to fix it myself, i mean it was 2 months ago, but still thanks, i will mark it as correct.

Comment: no problem i was just passing by and saw it , if some people have the same issue at least they have some clues on what is the error